# Is there an easy way to intercept and prevent an index change in QComboBox based on some condition?

Tags: c++, qt

The idea is to inform the user about side-effects of an initiated index change and allow to back out without actually changing the index if needed.

I can probably implement it by somehow identifying the index the combo is switching from and revert back to it after the fact, but it would be nice to be able to just stop the index change before it happens.

There is the event filter, but it's not immediately obvious to me how to translate say a mouse event to the combo index being selected.

Answer (score 0):

you may use the `enabled` property of ComboBox class. An example would be:

```
property bool controller: true

Button {
    id: id_testButton
    x: 46
    anchors.left: id_testComboBox.right
    text: "Click me to control combobox"
    anchors.top : parent.top
    anchors.leftMargin: 56
    anchors.topMargin: 21
    visible: true
    width: 198
    height: 50

    onClicked: {
        if (!controller)
            controller = true
        else
            controller = false
    }

}

ComboBox {
    id: id_testComboBox
    x: 261
    anchors.top: parent.top
    anchors.topMargin: 21
    anchors.rightMargin: 15
    width: 50 * 4
    height: 50
    visible: true
    model: ["1", "2", "3", "4"]

    enabled: {
        return controller
    }
}
```

You can change the conditions and specific elements as you wish, such as enabling and disabling after a specific value, etc. It is up to you.

Comment: I want the combo box and all the items in it to be enabled all the time, but prompt the user to confirm if he actually wants to proceed with a new index, and if not stay at the current selection.